# watir gem install error due to mini_magick file w/ special characters

Tags: ruby, installation, nokogiri, watir, minimagick

I have been trying to install the watir gem for ruby 2. I followed the watir books install instructions exactly but once the watir install get to the mini_magick gem it gives this error

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/tes
t/files/special! "chars'.gif`

Anyone know how to get around this? I noticed that nokogiri was acting kind of weird being unable to convert from ASCII to ITF-8. Maybe this has something to do with it. Thanks y'all

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran into same problem and here was my solution to work around it. The problem seems to be in the new 3.6.0 version, so back out the new version and install the previous version.

```
gem uninstall mini_magick
gem install mini_magick -v 3.5.0
```

After installing 3.5.0 mini_magick gem, rerun the watir gem install. It should find the mini_magick gem already installed and skip over it and install the remaining gems successfully. Good luck.

Comment: Yep and I really do not understand why is there so many gem that do not install without chose under-version

Comment: The problem is also mentiond in the mini_magick issue: https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/145